# Unable to sign in to Windows Live Online Account

Tags: google, online-accounts

I'm trying to sign in to my Windows Live account through *System Settings → Online Accounts*. After entering my credentials I can see the page asking me to allow Ubuntu access the account. After it, I see the initial page and account does not appear. That's what I see in the console:

```
(gnome-control-center:4915): account-plugin-WARNING **: AuthSession error: GDBus.Error:com.google.code.AccountsSSO.SingleSignOn.Error.NoConnection: Host  not found

(gnome-control-center:4915): credentials-cc-panel-CRITICAL **: cc-credentials-authorization-page.vala:182: Error completing auth session process: GDBus.Error:com.google.code.AccountsSSO.SingleSignOn.Error.NoConnection: Host  not found
```

The same happens with Google account. Can anyone explain what happens and how do I connect to my accounts?